# Understand @autoreleasepool inside loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have did some research about this topic. Like this post: [Under ARC, is it still advisable to create an @autoreleasepool for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825976/under-arc-is-it-still-advisable-to-create-an-autoreleasepool-for-loops)

But I still have one more question about it.
For example, given 2 code pieces.
One is like this:

```
for (...) {
   ...create some local variables...
}
```

Another one is like this:

```
for (...) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    ...create some local variables...
  }
}
```

I know for the second one, each new loop the local variables will be recycled. But for the first one, I also think in each new loop, the local variables will be recycled since each loop the local variables are out of the scope, so they should be taken care by ARC.

So, why should I use the second one?

Comment: Read the 2nd answer to the question you linked.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979384/why-does-the-position-of-autoreleasepool-matter

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, pretty useful!